# Respawning Factorial

Tags: code-golf

Write a program that does one step of the computation of factorial, then, generate (quine) a new program, and performs the rest of the process in the new program
The seed and spawned programs will have a variable n for the factorial to be computed and m for the accumulator.

I don't care if you use scripted or compiled language.
You can use the cheat of "reading the source file".
You MUST create a new file and run the new file to qualify: no self-modifying code or using code loaded in memory, but spawning with `data:` url in JS is allowed.

Here is an example in Java: https://gist.github.com/968033

Shortest code wins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Perl, 95

```perl
$m=1;$n=12||die$m;@ARGV=$0;$_=<>;$m*=$n--;s/\|/;\$m=$m;\$n=$n|/;open _,">$0";print _;exec$^X,$0
```

The program really has to be on a single line, and overwrites itself at each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (163)

```js
g=document.location;if(s=g.search.split(",")[1]){
n=s.split(":");i=n[1];n=n[0];i*=--n;
n==1?alert(i):g.search="?a=,"+n+":"+i}
else{n=prompt();g.search="?a=,"+n+":"+n}
```

This uses the querystring to pass values and refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0):

## Python (189)

It's not very short but it does take its argument on the command line.

```py
n,m=0,1
from sys import*
a,f=argv,file
_,n=a[0],len(a)>1and n<1and int(a[1])or n
if n>1:x=f(_).readlines();x[0]='n,m=%s\n'%`n-1,m*n`;f(_,'w').write(''.join(x));exec f(_).read()
else:print m
```